# エスケープしたファイルパスを渡したい。

Tags: macos, shell

VSCode拡張のRun on Saveというのを使ってファイル保存時に特定のコマンドを実行できるようにしてあります。
特定のコマンドが下記になります。

```
"cmd": "echo '${relativeFile}' | sed -e 's:frontend/::; s/(/\\\\(/g; s/)/\\\\)/g;' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'"
```

これは保存時のファイルパス（relativeFileに格納されている）を元にコンテナ内にインストールされたBiomeというフォーマッターとリンターを兼ね備えたライブラリを実行して保存したコードを整形してもらっています。

ただNext.jsのapp routerのグループ機能を使ったファイルパスだと途中でフォルダ名に `()` が入るためファイルによって、シンタックスエラーでBiomeが実行されなくなります。

それを回避するためにエスケープする置換処理を入れているのですが、 `xargs -I{} sh -c`を通った時にかけたエスケープが外れてしまいシンタックスエラーになります。

```
# () フォルダをエスケープする処理
echo 'frontend/neumann-client/src/app/(main)/page.tsx' | sed -e 's:frontend/::; s/(/\\(/g; s/)/\\)/g;'

# 実行結果
neumann-client/src/app/\(main\)/page.tsx
```

```
# xargs -I{} sh -c に通すとかけたエスケープが外れてしまう。
echo 'neumann-client/src/app/\(main\)/page.tsx' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'

# 実行されるコマンド、これだと()の部分でシンタックスエラーになる
docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply neumann-client/src/app/(main)/page.tsx
```

上記を解消するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。シェルスクリプトに詳しい方ご教授お願いいたします。

#### 実行環境

apple silicon macOS sonoma

### 追記

```
echo 'neumann-client/src/app/\(main\)/page.tsx' | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'
```

これでSave時にコマンドが上手く実行されたが

```
echo 'neumann-client/src/app/\\(main\\)/page.tsx' | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'
```

これだと '(' シンタックスエラーになる

```
"cmd": "echo '${relativeFile}' | sed -e 's:frontend/::; s/(/\\(/g; s/)/\\)/g;' | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'echo docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'"
```

Comment: もし解決したのであれば質問に直接追記するのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。

Comment: 回答してくださっていた方の回答が消えてしまいました。結論に至った過程が消えてしまい残念です。

Answer (score 0):

### 結論

下記の設定で期待する動作になりました。
Run on Save の関係もありエスケープする記述がおそらく通常のコマンドを実行するより、たくさん必要でした。

```
echo 'neumann-client/src/app/(main)/page.tsx' | sed -e 's:frontend/::; s/(/\\\\(/g; s/)/\\\\)/g;' | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'docker compose -f docker-compose.frontend.yml -p frontend exec -T frontend npx @biomejs/biome check --apply {}'
```